# Unable to open a javascript bookmarklet I created in new window or tab

Tags: bookmarklet

First off I know very little about code and learn from looking at how other example work.

I've created a bookmarklet that works fine, but I really want it to open in a new tab or window.

Here is the code currently being used:

```
<a href='javascript:q = "" +(window.getSelection ?  window.getSelection() : document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text); if (!q) q = prompt("Find the QSR of a search phrase, Simply enter a phrase wrapped in Quotes", ""); if (q!=null) location="http://www.google.com/search?q= " + escape(q).replace(/ /g, ""+"")+"&start=900#" ; void 0' ;
        <font color="#000000">QSR</font></a>
```

So the idea behind this bookmarklet is to find the total number of search results Google has has a phrase wrapped in quotes.  Clicking on QSR you would enter the phrase in quotes, What I'd like is when you click OK, it opens in a new tab or window.

I also noticed that if I highlight some text on a page and then press my QSR bookmarklet it will use the highlighted text to perform the search, but again I need this to open in a new tab or window.

I've been trying to figure this out but not having any luck, is this even possible?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
location="http://www.google.com/search?q= " + escape(q).replace(/ /g, ""+"")+"&start=900#"
```

to

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q= " + escape(q).replace(/ /g, ""+"")+"&start=900#")
```